# React native ActivityIndicator appearing after async load from database instead of before

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, asynchronous

I use the `ActivityIndicator` to show the user of my native React app that data is being retrieved from the database.
So in this case, the user selects a vehicle generation with the `Picker` and I retrieve all the vehicle types for that generation.
The problem is that the ActivityIndicator is not displayed directly, but a few seconds after the selection, after the data has been loaded from the database and I dont know why.These are the relevant code snippets:

```
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
...
const getAllTypesForGeneration = async (generationId) => {
  console.log("Getting types...");
  const types = await DataStore.query(CarType, (type) =>
    type.carGenerationID.eq(generationId)
  );
  setAllTypes(types);
  console.log("Got types...");
  setIsLoading(false);
};
...
return (
  <View>
    <View style={styles.activity}>
      <ActivityIndicator
        animating={isLoading}
        size="large"
        color={colors.primary}
      />
    </View>
   ...
    <Picker
      mode="dropdown"
      onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => {
        if (itemValue !== "") {
          setIsLoading(true);
          setSelectedCarGeneration(allGenerations[itemIndex - 1]);
          getAllTypesForGeneration(itemValue);
        }
      }}
    >
  ...
  </View>
);
```

The CarType table is pretty big, with about ~20000 entries. I happened to come across a strange phenomenon. I also have a function to get all generations for a specific model, this generations table consists of ~900 entries.

```
const getAllGenerationsForModel = async (modelId) => {
    const generations = await DataStore.query(CarGeneration, (generation) =>
      generation.carModelID.eq(modelId)
    );
    setAllGenerations(generations);
    setIsLoading(false);
  };
```

When I added this `getAllGenerationsForModel` function in the Picker before the `getAllTypesForGeneration(itemValue);` like:

```
<Picker
          mode="dropdown"
          onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => {
            if (itemValue !== "") {
              setIsLoading(true);
              setSelectedCarGeneration(allGenerations[itemIndex - 1]);
              getAllGenerationsForModel(itemValue);
              getAllTypesForGeneration(itemValue);
            }
          }}
        >
```

everything worked perfectly and the ActivityIndicator showed directly.